# Error projection for a stratified sample design from a finite population

Tags: python, package, projection

Strata: A B C

Strata Size: 100,100,1000

Sample Size: 20, 20, 30

Error Found: 1, 3, 4

---

I am looking for a way to project the number of errors back onto each stratum with lower bound and upper bound.  In in the cases where error rate is 0% or 100% (due to small sample sizes) for a certain stratum, we can run into projecting over the 100% or below  the 0%, which we have to use something like a hyper geometric projection.

My question is: is there any Python or R packages that can help me do this?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Not really sure what you're doing here - can you provide an example pre stratification?

Comment: It is stratified by location, so A, B, and C are just different locations.